# How to concatenate two node-sets such that order is respected?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

My understanding has been that, despite the fact that XSLT's "node-sets" are called "sets", they are, in fact, ordered lists of nodes (which is why each node is associated with an index). I've therefore been trying to use the "|" operator to concatenate node-sets such that the order of the nodes is respected.

What I am attempting to accomplish is something like the following JavaScript code:

```
[o1,o2,o3].concat([o4,o5,o6])
```

Which yields:

```
[o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6]
```

But, consider the following reduced example:

testFlatten.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="parentTransition" select="//*[@id='parentTransition']"/>
  <xsl:variable name="childTransition" select="//*[@id='childTransition']"/>
  <xsl:variable name="parentThenChildTransitions" select="$parentTransition | $childTransition"/>
  <xsl:variable name="childThenParentTransitions" select="$childTransition | $parentTransition"/>

  <return>
   <parentThenChildTransitions>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$parentThenChildTransitions"/>
   </parentThenChildTransitions>
   <childThenParentTransitions>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$childThenParentTransitions"/>
   </childThenParentTransitions>
  </return>

 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
        <element id="parentTransition"/>

 <element id="childTransition"/>
</root>
```

Which yields (with xsltproc):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<return>
    <parentThenChildTransitions>
        <element id="parentTransition"/><element id="childTransition"/>
    </parentThenChildTransitions>
    <childThenParentTransitions>
        <element id="parentTransition"/><element id="childTransition"/>
    </childThenParentTransitions>
</return>
```

So the "|" operator in fact does not respect the order of the node-set operands. Is there a way I can concatenate node-sets such that order is respected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is actually not an XSLT but an XPath question.**

In XPath 1.0 there isn't anything similar to a "list" datatype. A node-set is a set and it has no order.

In XPath 2.0 there is the *sequence* data type. Any items in a sequence are ordered. This has nothing to do with document order. Also, the same item (or node) can appear more than once in a sequence.

**So, in XSLT 2.0 one just uses the XPath 2.0 sequence concatenation operator `,`:**

```
//*[@id='parentTransition'] , //*[@id='childTransition']
```

and this evaluates to the sequence of all elements in the document with `id` attribute `'parentTransition'` followed by all elements in the document with `id` attribute `'childTransition'`

**In XSLT it is still possible to access and process nodes not in document order**: for example using the `<xsl:sort>` instruction -- however the set of nodes that are processed as result of `<xsl:apply-templates>` or `<xsl:for-each>` is a `node-list` -- not a node-set.

**Another example of evaluating nodes not in document order** is the `position()` function within `<xsl:apply-templates>` or `<xsl:for-each>` that have a `<xsl:sort>`  child or within a predicate of a location step (of an XPath expression) in which a reverse axis is used (such as `ancesstor::` or `preceeding::`)

Answer (score 3):

In XSLT 1.0, you can process nodes in a selected order (for example by use of xsl:sort), but you can't hold a list of nodes in a variable. The only thing you can hold in a variable (or pass to a template, etc) is a node-set; node-sets have no intrinsic order, but when you process them, they are always processed in document order unless you use xsl:sort to request a different processing order.

You might be able to solve your problem by copying the nodes:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$ns0"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$ns1"/>
</xsl:variable>
...
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($temp/*)"/>
```

but this depends on your use-case.

Switch to XSLT 2.0 if you can!

Answer (score 1):

The "|" operator will retain nodes in document order. In XSLT 1.0 you will need to have sequential `copy` or `for-each` operations.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$parentTransition"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="$childTransition"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not clear to me how copy or for-each could be used to combine node-sets without using the exslt node-set() function to parse the subsequent document fragment. Could you provide a code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: $parentTranslation *is* a node-set and the code above combines two node-sets in a given order. Reversing the two statements would output the nodesets in the opposite order

Comment: If you want to do more specialised maniuplation of nodesets then you can't use XSLT1.0.

Comment: Oh, and listen to anything @Michael Kay says - he is the world expert!