# XSLT - Tricky Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble with an XSLT transformation of XML fragments. The source XML looks like so:

```
<XXX>
    <Name>Sample</Name>
    <MMM>
        <AAA ID="A"/>
        <MMM>
            <BBB ID="B"/>
            <MMM>
                <AA ID="C"/>
                <BB ID="D"/>
            </MMM>
        </MMM>
    </MMM>
</XXX>
```

But it needs to be transformed into:

```
<XXX>
    <Name>Sample</Name>
    <MMM>
        <MMM>
            <MMM>
                <AAA ID="A"/>
                <BBB ID="B"/>
            </MMM>
            <AA ID="C"/>            
        </MMM>
        <BB ID="D"/>
    </MMM>
</XXX>
```

The rule is simple, the MMM element can only have two child element nodes. If only one of those nodes happen to be another MMM, it needs to occupy the first position.

It is easy using code, but these XML fragments are values to XML columns in an SQL database, and I want to use SQL along with XSLT to update those values.

Any pointer or suggestions?

Comment: The way you defined the rule is not reflected in your output XML. How I understand your rule it would look like:
`<XXX>
    <Name>Sample</Name>
    <MMM>
        <MMM>
            <MMM>
                <AA ID="C"/>
                <BB ID="D"/>
            </MMM>
            <BBB ID="B"/>
        </MMM>
        <AAA ID="A"/>
    </MMM>
</XXX>`

Comment: True, but the resulting XML is the intended target, the AAA & BBB should retain their traversal order as in the first.

Comment: You're not only switching nodes, you're also moving them to lower or higher levels, like AAA from level 2 to level 4, and AA from level 4 to level 3... that's what troubles me

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: would xslt 2.0 be ok?

Comment: One more thing: can we assume that the depth of the tree always monotonously increases and then decreases again? Or can there be `MMM` nodes that have two non-empty `MMM` nodes as children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to first extract the `MMM` tree on the one hand and the *other* nodes on the other hand into separate structures and then to merge them again.

This was really a nice challenge! Made me stay up until 4:00 AM.

The following XSLT (almost! see below) does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
   <!-- handling of MMM extraction -->
   <xsl:template match="MMM" mode="extract_mmm">
      <MMM>
         <xsl:apply-templates mode="extract_mmm" />
      </MMM>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*" mode="extract_mmm" />
   <!-- handling of extraction of other nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="MMM" mode="extract_other">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="extract_other" />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*" mode="extract_other">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </xsl:template>
   <!-- handling of merging the two partial result sets -->
   <xsl:template match="MMM" mode="dump">
      <xsl:param name="others" />
      <xsl:choose>
         <!-- this handles the case of an MMM being a leaf node -->
         <xsl:when test="count(MMM) = 0">
            <xsl:variable name="nodes_in_next_sibling" select="2*count(following-sibling::MMM)" />
            <MMM>
               <xsl:copy-of select="$others[count($others) - $nodes_in_next_sibling - 1]" />
               <xsl:copy-of select="$others[count($others) - $nodes_in_next_sibling]" />
            </MMM>
         </xsl:when>
         <!-- this handles the case of an inner MMM with a sibling -->
         <xsl:when test="count(../MMM) = 2">
            <xsl:variable name="free_positions_in_second_child" select="count(MMM[position() = 2 and count(MMM) = 0])*2 + count(MMM[2]//MMM[count(MMM) = 0])*2 + count(MMM[position() = 2 and count(MMM) = 1]) + count(MMM[2]//MMM[count(MMM) = 1])" />
            <MMM>
               <xsl:apply-templates mode="dump" select="MMM[1]">
                  <xsl:with-param name="others" select="$others[position() &lt; count($others)- $free_positions_in_second_child + 1]" />
               </xsl:apply-templates>
               <xsl:apply-templates mode="dump" select="MMM[2]">
                  <xsl:with-param name="others" select="$others[position() &gt;= count($others) - $free_positions_in_second_child + 1]" />
               </xsl:apply-templates>
            </MMM>
         </xsl:when>
         <!-- this handles the case of an inner MMM without sibling -->
         <xsl:when test="count(../MMM) = 1">
            <MMM>
               <xsl:apply-templates mode="dump">
                  <xsl:with-param name="others" select="$others[position() &lt; count($others)]" />
               </xsl:apply-templates>
            </MMM>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$others[position() = count($others)]" />
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="XXX">
      <XXX>
         <xsl:copy-of select="Name" />
         <xsl:variable name="mmm_structure">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="extract_mmm" select="MMM" />
         </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:variable name="other_structure_tmp">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="extract_other" select="MMM" />
         </xsl:variable>
         <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610921/how-to-concatenate-two-node-sets-such-that-order-is-respected -->
         <!-- http://www.exslt.org/exsl/ -->
         <xsl:variable name="other_structure" select="exslt:node-set($other_structure_tmp/*)" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$mmm_structure" mode="dump">
            <xsl:with-param name="others" select="$other_structure" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </XXX>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes:

- This is still pretty much XSLT 1.0 with EXSLT extensions.
- `MMM` nodes with two children are also handled. The rule of placing the *other* nodes is such that the positions are filled from the bottom to the top.
- In this version the *other* nodes are moved down as far as possible without violating the 2 children max rule. So the output is not exactly as display in the question but rather as follows.

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<XXX>
  <Name>Sample</Name>
  <MMM>
    <MMM>
      <MMM>
        <AAA ID="A"/>
        <AAA ID="B"/>
      </MMM>
    </MMM>
    <BBB ID="C"/>
  </MMM>
  <BBB ID="D"/>
</XXX>
```

If this is a problem let me know.

Comment: Some of the `count` expressions in the XSLT can be simplified. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618479/concise-expression-for-counting-leaf-nodes-in-specific-subtrees.

Comment: I just noticed that my third note (see above) actually does need attention since I left a gap that should not be there (after the closing `MMM` between `B` and `C`. Will have to look into this...

Comment: Although I had to abandon the approach due to an architectural change, I'm keeping the item open for a while as it seems like a good challenge, giving all something to learn. I will post my attempts as well later. Thank you for your input!