# Concise expression for counting leaf nodes in specific subtrees

Tags: xslt, xpath

In my attempt to answer question [XSLT - Tricky Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031880/xslt-tricky-transformation) I came across the following task:

> For each tag `<MMM>` count the number of leaf nodes in the second
>   `<MMM>` child tag.

Define "leaf node" as an `<MMM>` tag that does not have other `<MMM>` tags as children. It may have other tags as children, though.

I ended up with two expressions:

```
<xsl:variable name="just_children" select="count(MMM[position() = 2 and count(MMM) = 0])"/>
<xsl:variable name="grandchildren_and_below" select="count(MMM[2]//MMM[count(MMM) = 0])"/>
```

The first one counts the leafs in the second child, the second one in all ancestors of the second child. I was not able to combine these two into one expression (except for the obvious summing which I have to do :-) ). Somehow I cannot make the node array index selector `[2]`, the additional condition `count(MMM) = 0`, and the ancestor path `//' fit into the same expression.

So, is there more a concise (and probably more elegant) way to write this expression?

Thanks a lot!

For testing you can use this input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<MMM>
  <MMM>
    <MMM>
      <MMM/>
      <MMM/>
    </MMM>    
    <MMM>
      <MMM/>
      <MMM>
        <MMM/>
      </MMM>
    </MMM>
  </MMM>
  <MMM>
    <MMM/>
  </MMM>
</MMM>
```

and the following XSLT sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="MMM">
    <xsl:variable name="just_children" select="count(MMM[position() = 2 and count(MMM) = 0])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="grandchildren_and_below" select="count(MMM[2]//MMM[count(MMM) = 0])"/>
    <MMM just_children="{$just_children}" grandchildren_and_below="{$grandchildren_and_below}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </MMM>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **just_children** variable could be written as this:

```
<xsl:variable name="just_children" select="count(MMM[2][not(MMM)])"/>
```

And your **grandchildren_and_below** variable could be written as this:

```
<xsl:variable name="grandchildren_and_below" select="count(MMM[2]//MMM[not(MMM)])"/>
```

To put them both together as one, you could use the **descendant-or-self** axes, like so

```
<xsl:variable name="all" select="count(MMM[2]//descendant-or-self::MMM[not(MMM)])"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tim. I never thought of the axis `descendant-or-self` since so far I only used axes when I wanted to "go away" from the context node. So, now although I see the pattern `MMM` three times the second occurrence is only optional and this covers the direct children, too.